# Server-Side Events / EventSource / PostgreSQL Notify - only when transaction in DB

Tags: php, postgresql, notify, eventsource

I am trying to let client(browser) know when there is a transaction in database.
I am using EventSource in JS to connect with PHP where I 'listen' to PostgreSQL DB.
What is happening is that the EventSource listens or reads data every 3-4 seconds even though I have not set anything about it.
My intention is to **get notified only when there is a transaction in DB** and only when DB shoots 'notify'.

**PROBLEM**: The EventSource is listening every 3-4 seconds like polling and it notifies me multiple times even though there was one notification from DB.
**CONCERN**: I am connecting DB every time it runs through PHP and this SSE feels like polling.

### JavaScript

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("sse.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    };
} else {
    console.log("SSE NOT SUPPORTED");
}
```

### PHP

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$conn = pg_pconnect("DB INFO HERE") or die('DB CONNECT ERROR');
pg_query($conn, 'LISTEN event_insert;');
$notify = pg_get_notify($conn);

if (!$notify) {
    echo "data: .\n\n";
} else {
    $msg = json_encode($notify);
    echo "data: {$msg}\n\n";
}

flush();
```

### PostgreSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_event_insert() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  NOTIFY event_insert;
  RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_event_insert AFTER INSERT ON events
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_event_insert();
```

### JS CONSOLE

I get '.' when there is no transaction, and I get JSON when there is transaction and the DB 'notifies' me.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Polling is what it is [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-notify.php) to do:

> Otherwise if no NOTIFY is waiting, then FALSE is returned.

Maybe you want to use PDO's pgsqlGetNotify instead.

Comment: I don't quite get it. So, you mean NOTIFY has to be listened in an infinite loop in order to keep listening? I don't want it to be polling. I do not want to put it in a forever-true while loop just like the last example in this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-notify.php) at the very bottom.

Comment: pg_get_notify will poll, immediately return false if nothing is pending.  pgsqlGetNotify will block until it gets a message (or it timesout, if you use the timeout).  If you want to keep listening after the first message/non-message, you have to loop.  What other option would there be?

Comment: Okay. So, pg_get_notify is polling. It is good to know. I was looking for event handler type of method. To me, pgsqlgetnotify seems what I am looking for. Without looping it, can I still get notified close to real-time when there is a new transaction (DB Notify)? I want to get notified whenever DB notifes but I do not want polling.